# cuda-memcheck Invalid __global__ read of size 4

Tags: cuda

Hi I am trying to debug a cuda code with cpp wrapper. The cpp function is used in PyTorch code(test.py) as a custom extension. When I run
`cuda-memcheck python test.py`

After few iterations, I get this error

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x00000ed8 in /tmp/pip-req-build-9fowbxbl/test_ops2/_ext-src/sr
c/geo_query_gpu.cu:770:query_geo_point_kernel(int, int, int, float, int, float c
onst *, float const *, int*, int*, float const *, int const *, int const *, int*
, int const *, int const *, int const *, float const *, int const *, int const *
, int const *, int const *, int const *, int const *, int const *, int const *, 
int const *, int const *, int const *, float*, float*, bool*, int*, int*)
=========     by thread (210,0,0) in block (15,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7fc938c00000 is out of bounds
```

I want to understand the exact meaning of this error. I believe its because of out of bound addressing happening on line 770 of my code. But what does few terms indicate here?
`at 0x00000ed8` is common during every test. What does this indicate?

The error says `Address 0x7fc938c00000 is out of bounds`. What does this address represent here?

I am not seeking the exact source of errors in my code in this question. I am trying to understand the meaning of this error log.

Comment: It means the instruction at `0x00000ed8` in your code is making an out of bounds memory read or using an invalid address to attempt to read from global memory. If you compile your code with the `--generate-line-info` option, you will get to see the source line which is the cause. Otherwise you will need to disassemble the SASS of your kernel to see the offending machine code instruction and its arguments

Comment: Thank you @talonmies for your reply. Is it possible to check the instruction at ```0x00000ed8``` by any method? I used -lineinfo flag during my nvcc build. Is ```--generate-line-info``` different from that?

Comment: No it is the same. However you are building the code must either be ignoring the flag or stripping out the line information from the symbols table

Comment: I get a whole bunch of error log below this like this ```Host Frame:/home/test_ops2/_ext.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so (_Z22query_geo_point_kerneliiifiPKfS0_PiS1_S0_PKiS3_S1_S3_S3_S3_S0_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_S3_PfS4_PbS1_S1_ + 0xb9) [0x3e51c]```
Is this the result due to -line-info flag?

To add to this, with using the -lineinfo flag I could see the line 770 in my error message which was not present otherwise.

Comment: OK I missed that in your output. So it is working. Line 770 in your code is the culprit. Time to start debugging

Comment: Read of size 4 bytes...  If I had to bet, this is a handle of some sort, like the CUDA or cuDNN handles.

Answer (score 1):

> `at 0x00000ed8` is common during every test. What does this indicate?

That is the address of the instruction that caused the fault.

> The error says Address 0x7fc938c00000 is out of bounds. What does this address represent here?

It represents the address where the instruction indicated a `__global__` read of size 4 should happen.  However that address is "out of bounds" meaning it is not part of any valid memory allocation in use by your program.

Comment: ``` meaning it is not part of any valid memory allocation in use by your program ```
Do you mean that it is not caused by my code like some more than size indexing in any array?

Comment: it is definitely caused by your code.  In host code, for example, if you allocated a device array of size 30 for example using `cudaMalloc`, and your device code attempted to index into that array at index 42, that would be a memory location that is not part of any valid memory allocation in use by your program.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it's because of my code I observed now. Will try to debug it!